Realistic examples of http request headers, difference between HTTP_FORWARDED, HTTP_X_FORWARDED, , HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR headers
I am working on a task where I need to fetch the IP of client from http request header.
(java junit testcases need to be developed ofr each of the headers)
I am using following list of headers based on order of most widely used first.
"X-Forwarded-For",
"Proxy-Client-IP",
"WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
"HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
"X-Cluster-Client-IP",
"HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
"HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
"HTTP_FORWARDED",
"HTTP_VIA",
"REMOTE_ADDR"
Now I understand headers such as x_forwarded_For and http_x_forwarded-for are one and same.
I understand these headers are easy to spoof and non - standardized.

But how about other headers especially HTTP_X_FORWARDED, HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR, HTTP_FORWARDED etc?

Are they same ?

Can I use same examples for each of these headers ? or can someone post some valid examples for these headers.

I tried to search a log for examples with headers Proxy-CLient-IP, http_CLIENT_IP, HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLINET_IP as well. But I got examples where only a single value is present for each of these headers.


5.Are there any realistic examples where a list of IPs are present separated by some character such as comma or semicolon ?
Please help.
I used following examples based on my research already in junit testcases:
//Forwarded: type headers
"for=103.0.113.165, for=198.51.100.17;proto=https;host=xxx.yyy.com;by=10.97.9.10";
"for="103.0.113.165:64822"";
"for=192.168.2.43, for=198.51.100.17;proto=https;host=xxx.yyy.com;by=10.97.9.10";
"For="[2001:db8:cafe::17]:4711"";
"2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:1.2.3.4";
"103.0.113.165, 60.91.3.17, 120.192.338.678"; //Comma separated list for X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_X_FOWARDED_FOR headers.
"1.0 fred, 1.1 p.example.net";// VIA header
